# Azure Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, graph-api-explorer, azure-ad-graph-api

Even though I've added apps from gallery to Azure AD, I cannot see when I try to pull the data. But I can see the custom apps added. Like if I've added 7 apps; 2 from gallery(Google Docs, One drive) & 5 custom(native/web apps); I am able to see only 5 apps! Am I going wrong any where? 
The Graph API that am using is:

```
https://graph.windows.net/mycustomad.onmicrosoft.com/applications?api-version=beta
```

I tried with different api versions but no luck.
Can someone suggest me on this?

Answer (score 2):

In graph API, "applications" represent application configuration that developers register in their tenant.  Gallery apps are no different (and happen to be registered in a special tenant).  When you acquire an application (like a gallery app, or consent to a custom application someone else has developed), an application instance gets created in your tenant so that we can attach policy and permissions to it.  This application instance is called a "service principal".

You can query for this using:
https://graph.windows.net/mycustomad.onmicrosoft.com/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.5

This will return ALL acquired apps, and some default Microsoft apps.

Hope this explains why your query of the application entity shows only the custom apps you've registered in your tenant.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for this. And for filtering the default microsoft apps, am just pulling apps which has only Homepage; where this would be null for them. Is this valid to do so?

Comment: But if I like to pull app metadata like logo, those properties are available only in Applications but not on ServicePrincipals.

Comment: For App metadata, I've pulled service principals first & then trying to get app by ID(which is available in Service Principal). When i now try to get app which is installed from gallery, its kicking me off saying object is not present. :(